# What does the carnie say?

Tags: dialogue, downton-abbey

In the Season 3 Christmas Special of Downton Abbey, after Daisy wins the gold sovereign in the ring toss, the carnie running the ring toss says something to his assistant that I couldn't understand. What does he say?

I watched it several times, and tried turning subtitles on, but this line didn't have subtitles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full episodes are gone from the Masterpiece website so I can't check the exact wording, but it was something like "I told you to set the expensive prizes up higher."